# ((Any) throws -> Bool) throws -> Optional<Any>') cannot conform to 'BinaryInteger'

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, watchconnectivity

I am facing an issue trying to convert message from apple watch's WC session [String: Any] as I am customizing a sample project that retrieves heart rate from apple watch and send it to iPhone. I am hoping that I can get some help as I am already struggling with watchconnectivity for 3 days.

I do see that I am receiving the message properly from Apple Watch and I am close to utilize the message received to update heart rate at iOS app side. But I think the "guard let" statement is causing the didReceiveMessage function to stop half way.

I am not sure, but I think if I can "unwrap" the message ["rate": 61] into 61 in double format, I should be able to pass the guard let function and get this function working.

[image]

[image]

On top of that I am seeing another error saying "NO with WCErrorCodeDeliveryFailed", but I am not sure why this is being populated as I already implemented suggested solutions from other SO answers. But I think this error is redundant/unrelated to above error message.

[image]

Would appreciate help.

```
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

protocol WatchKitConnectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didFinishedActiveSession()
    func updateLatestHeartRate(_ LatestHeartRate: Double)
}

protocol WatchKitConnectionProtocol {
    func startSession()
    func sendMessage(message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: (([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)?, errorHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?)
}

class WatchKitConnection: NSObject {
    static let shared = WatchKitConnection()
    weak var delegate: WatchKitConnectionDelegate?
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    func sendHeartRate(rate: Int) {
        WCSession.default.sendMessage(["rate": rate], replyHandler: nil) { error in
            print("Failed to send message: \(error)")
        }

        print("from iOS watchkit connection")
    }

extension WatchKitConnection: WatchKitConnectionProtocol {
    func startSession() {
        session?.delegate = self
        session?.activate()
    }
    
    func sendMessage(message: [String : AnyObject],
                     replyHandler: (([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)? = nil,
                     errorHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)? = nil)
    
    {
        validReachableSession?.sendMessage(message, replyHandler: { (result) in
            print(result)
            print("success in phone sendmessage function")
        }, errorHandler: { (error) in
            print("error in phone sendmessage function")
            print(error)
        })
    }
    
}

extension WatchKitConnection: WCSessionDelegate {

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        print("didReceiveMessage from watch")
        print(message)
        
        delegate?.updateLatestHeartRate(Double(message.values.first))
        
        guard let heartRate = message.values.first as? String? else {
            return
        }
        guard let heartRateDouble = Double(heartRate!) else {
            return
        }
        
        print("printing heartRate double from message\(heartRateDouble)")
        
        delegate?.updateLatestHeartRate(heartRateDouble)
        
        print("updateLatestHeartRate")
      }
```

WatchKitConnection Swift file at iOS App

Comment: Yes, you need to safely unwrap your optional value. You're trying to use `message.values.first` before you unwrap it on the next line. Unwrap first, then pass it to your delegate method.

Comment: Also, is `message.value.first` really a `String`? Or is it an `Int`? And if it is a string, you've got an extra `?` in there, e.g., it should be `guard let heartRate = message.values.first as? String else { ... }` (note, not `String?`).

Comment: thanks for your feedback, let me try, and the message is ["rate": 61] so it's an Int.

Comment: Be careful assuming it's an `Int` on the basis of the print statement. But if it was an integer, then it’s `guard let heartRate = message.values.first as? Int else { ... }`.

Comment: Also, I see a `!` in there. You really want to avoid doing force unwrapping operations, as if it fails, it will crash. But if you remove that extraneous `?`, you won't need to force unwrap it...

Comment: I changed to ```guard let heartRate = message.values.first as? Int else {
            return``` and then I am seeing another error saying "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Double'" in the line below. let me look up on this error...

Comment: Thanks Rob :) I managed to resolve this issue and get my delegate function running by removing the "guard let" statement since the right side of equation was non-optional in the first place. How do I thank you since you didn't post answer?

Comment: I'm happy with you posting your own answer. You'll be able to accept it in a day or so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [@Rob in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172617/any-throws-bool-throws-optionalany-cannot-conform-to-binaryintege/70173052#comment124046641_70172617), I was able to unwrap the message properly and remove unnecessary guard let statements to run my delegate function. Below is the updated piece of code.

1. Changed `message.values.first?` as `Int` as the rate was in an integer format.
2. Removed guard let statements in converting the `heartRate` into the double format, as it was non-optional.

```
extension WatchKitConnection: WCSessionDelegate {

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        print("didReceiveMessage from watch")
        print(message)
        
//        delegate?.updateLatestHeartRate(Double(message.values.first))
        
        guard let heartRate = message.values.first as? Int else {
            return
        }
        
        let heartRateDouble = Double(heartRate)
        
        print("printing heartRate double from message\(heartRateDouble)")
        
        delegate?.updateLatestHeartRate(heartRateDouble)
        
        print("updateLatestHeartRate")
        
    }
}
```